# Does stack overflow use LSI (Latent Semantic Indexing) to generate the list of related questions

Tags: support, search-indexing

I am building a website for tagging/titling fragments of text content from our archive of transcribed discourses. There are many features that I would like to mimic from Stack Overflow. Particularly the feature when you type in a title and a list of related titles is dynamically generated, so you can see if there is already a title similar to yours in use.

I love the way this works in SO, however, I was curious to know if the developers had ever thought about using Latent Semantic Indexing to match the actual text content of the user's question with other entries in SO (the text content - NOT the titles), after the user has finished writing his question.

These could then be presented to the user before he confirms his new post (like the related questions list) - or dynamically as he is typing the question.

Anyway - this is the kind of feature I am looking to implement in my application - so I just thought I'd ask if it was being used here.

Comment: @Braiam are you trying to burninate the [tag:text] tag?

Comment: @Luuklag [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366648/is-this-text-useful). When there's no active protest, we can safely remove the tag.

Comment: @Braiam that said, please don't remove other tags, some are still useful. Thanks. (talking for example about removing unicode tag)