# Is this [text] useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There’s a tag [text](/questions/tagged/text), with 24 questions and no excerpt or wiki. It seems to be used to refer to… text, somewhere on the site. This is a *wee* bit broad - there are a lot of different places text is present here! Posts, dropdowns, dialog boxes, tags, etc.

I’m not sure this is useful. Who is ever going to search for questions about the text of *anything*? It would be better to tag with where the text in question was found ([posts](/questions/tagged/posts) for [text in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363357), [comments](/questions/tagged/comments) for [text in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322757), etc.). Though, note that in both of those cases I linked a “location” tag *was* used. The tag [text](/questions/tagged/text) seems to have been to specify the question was specifically about the text, not about other aspects (e.g. reputation).

What should be done with this tag?

- Is it salvageable? Would an excerpt, wiki, and/or name-change make this into a useful tag?
- If it isn’t salvageable, should we get rid of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a few presses of the backspace key later, and we've deleted [text](/questions/tagged/text) from the system.

As is usual with this awesome community, there was plenty of additional cleanup along the way. Thanks to all who helped tidy up!

[image: Burnination dragon]

Answer (score 7):

Worth pointing out that since 2017 only six posts have included that tag which makes it virtually obsolete.

I suggest that in many cases [text](/questions/tagged/text) be replaced with [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) that says

> For the suggestion of improvements to the phrasing of text shown to users by the Stack Exchange engine.

While  [Disallow emojis in comments and posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344347/disallow-emojis-in-comments-and-posts) and [Preventing Zalgo text from spanning outside the box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/preventing-zalgo-text-from-spanning-outside-the-box) could benefit by being tagged [emoji](/questions/tagged/emoji) and [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) respectively. There are possibly other exceptions but I'll leave that decision to more expert hands.

Comment: I agree that 'text' can and should be replaced by more useful tags. Which tags that should be could be determined by whoever edits the tag out, as long as it's edited out. Vague tags serve no purpose.

Comment: Well 18 in total, we'll still need to handle the legacy stuff. I do guess its a classic 'meta' tag - and that should be a critical consideration here

Comment: Here is one case where "text" is better than "wording"; and there are a few more, but the oldest (visible) usage seems inconsistent with the *best* usage. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158759/282094